# Trying to decipher Python list comprehension

Tags: python, list

I haven't worked in Python in a few years and I am trying to figure out what a particular list comprehension means.

Here's the code:

```
cols = [i for i, col in enumerate(desc) if col[0].startswith('word')]
```

I am looking at the list comprehension page in the Python docs, and I am not seeing anything that would describe what having a comma and then a separate statement would mean.

How would this code look at a non-list comprehension?

Comment: It’s not a comma and a separate statement; it’s tuple unpacking. Think `i, col = item`. (Or `for i, col in enumerate(desc): …`)

Comment: Read `i, col` as a tuple `(i, col)`. Because enumerate() returns a list of tuples of 2 items

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How would this code look at a non-list comprehension?

```
cols = []
for i, col in enumerate(desc):
    if col[0].startswith('word'):
        cols.append(i)
```

Comment: Got it. Basically I'm grabbing the values inside the tuple created by enumerate.

Answer (score 1):

```
cols = [i for i, col in enumerate(desc) if col[0].startswith('word')]
```

is "short for"

```
cols = []
for i, col in enumerate(desc)
    if col[0].startswith('word'):
        cols.append(i)
```

So you should read the comma not as a separation of statements, but as a separation of values (e.g. `life, universe, everything = the_answer` or `li = [4, 2]`)

Answer (score 0):

It just depend on the number of values within an iterable which you loop over it.So the `for` keyword can followed by an arbitrary variable name.

And in this case since `enumerate()` contains the items of iterable with those index it used 2 variable `i, col`.

For more info about iterable unpacking read PEP 3131 https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/

> A tuple (or list) on the left side of a simple assignment (unpacking is not defined for augmented assignment) may contain at most one expression prepended with a single asterisk (which is henceforth called a "starred" expression, while the other expressions in the list are called "mandatory"). This designates a subexpression that will be assigned a list of all items from the iterable being unpacked that are not assigned to any of the mandatory expressions, or an empty list if there are no such items.